# Cd into first available directory in git bash?

Tags: bash, github-actions, git-bash

I know in Linux you can use `cd */` to get into the first available directory, however I need a way to get into the first directory using Git bash. I'm writing bash commands for Github Actions that will be run across Linux and Windows machines, so I need a cross-compatible solution.

Running `cd */` on Git bash gives me the error `bash: cd: too many arguments`.

Comment: Same thing in a Unix like environment, not just git bash. What do you mean by *first directory*

Comment: `*/` expands to all directories in the cwd, not the first one.

Comment: How would you determine the *first directory* ?

Comment: Depending on the shell, `cd */` does nothing except produce an error if `*/` expands to more than one directory.

Comment: Ah I think I misinterpreted this answer I found https://askubuntu.com/a/454691

Comment: By first directory I mean the first directory under the current working directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd */` does not "get into the first available directory." `*/` expands to the list of all directories in your current directory, which `cd` won't accept if there isn't exactly one directory.

You could use an array to capture the list and then cd into the first item in the list:

```
dirs=(*/)
cd "${dirs[0]}"
```